# Full code coverage

Tags: c#, string, code-coverage, writer

I'm trying to obtain full code coverage for the following line of code...

```
stringWriter.Write(HtmlEncodedString.Format(string.Format("{0,-10:C}", x + y)))
```

The line above this one is showing as fully covered and is just writing out a string but this one is only showing as partially covered.

Anybody have any ideas how I can make this line fully covered?

Comment: What CC tool are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Are there perhaps return codes or exceptions from either of the Format() methods that your tests do not currently trigger?